# Reversing order of a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list named scores. The values are [10,20,30,40]. I want to print these values in reversed order. At the moment I have Scores = [10, 20, 30, 40] on my first line but I am stuck here.

Comment: [Google search results](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#qscrl=1&q=python+reverse+list)

Comment: @SethMMorton it's a shame they don't allow LMGTFY links here

Comment: One way is `lst = list(reversed(lst))`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Scores = Scores[::-1]` #Scores now are reversed `[40, 30, 20, 10]`